# Remove matching line and following line from file

Tags: sed

I have the following in a file

```
######################

asd asd MISC/TEXT asd asd
data concering above line

bla bla bla SEARCH/TEXT bla bla bla
data concering above line

asd asd MISC/TEXT asd asd
data concering above line
#######################
```

How do I remove the line containing SEARCH/TEXT and the line following it?

EDIT - The block/paragraph is always two lines long

EDIT2 - Expanded example file for clarity

Comment: By "para" you mean paragraph?

Comment: how does the "data concerning above line" look like? fix number of lines? contains empty lines?

Comment: its only 1 line after the inital search line..

Comment: I hope my rewording of your question is suitable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

since you said only one data line after the pattern line:

```
sed '/SEARCH\/TEXT/{N;d;}' yourFile
```

**test**

```
kent$  echo "######################
bla bla bla SEARCH/TEXT bla bla bla
data concering above line

asd asd MISC/TEXT asd asd
data concering above line
#######################"|sed '/SEARCH\/TEXT/{N;d;}'
######################

asd asd MISC/TEXT asd asd
data concering above line
#######################
```

EDIT2:

**test** with new example input:

```
kent$  echo "######################
dquote> 
dquote> asd asd MISC/TEXT asd asd
dquote> data concering above line
dquote> 
dquote> bla bla bla SEARCH/TEXT bla bla bla
dquote> data concering above line
dquote> 
dquote> asd asd MISC/TEXT asd asd
dquote> data concering above line
dquote> #######################"|sed '/SEARCH\/TEXT/{N;d;}'
######################

asd asd MISC/TEXT asd asd
data concering above line


asd asd MISC/TEXT asd asd
data concering above line
#######################
```

Comment: It seems that this removes everything after that first result.